# Sub queries errors in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

I am trying to run a query of this sort on hive 0.12

```
Select A.a1,A.a2 from A Where A.a3 in (SELECT b1 FROM  B WHERE B.b4=A.a4)
```

And I get a syntax error,

As I read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) that hive 0.12 does not support inner queries.

How would you re-write this query in an efficient, equivalent way ?